# Maximum Flow Problem : Can someone refer me to accessible valuable resources

Tags: optimization, reference-request, graphs, network-flow, books

Can anyone please refer/suggest me some accessible papers, works, books, websites, documentation related to The Maximum Flow Problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://cs.yazd.ac.ir/hasheminezhad/STSCS4R1.pdf) is one suggestion : **Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications** by Ahuja, Magnanti, Orli.

The *maximum flow problem* is delt with in chapters 6-8, but I suggest you read the ones before if you are not familiar with flows in general.

Also, James Orlin (one of the authors, teaches at MIT) has a [webpage](https://mitmgmtfaculty.mit.edu/jorlin/network-flows/) where you can find solutions to some of the exercises.

Comment: Thank you very much, after two weeks of reading I have found all I needed in  the "Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications" ! Really appreciate your help

Comment: Happy to help ! Great book indeed

Answer (score 3):

A group of undergraduate students at Berkeley have a fantastic reading group on topics in TCS, and they are currently reading Max Flow. They have a [webpage](https://ugtcs.berkeley.edu/reading-groups/sp20/maxflow/) where they've curated recent papers with progress on the problem.